How do i solve this RangeError in flutter?
Theres a funtion i wrote that uses switch below
Widget buildVerdict(BuildContext context, bool firstGuessResult,
      bool? secondGuessResult, bool? thirdGuessResult) {
    switch (widget.noOfAttempts) {
      case 1:
        return firstGuessResult == true
            ? const Icon(
                Icons.check_box,
                color: Colors.green,
              )
            : Container();
      case 2:
        return firstGuessResult == true && secondGuessResult == true
            ? const Icon(
                Icons.check_box,
                color: Colors.green,
              )
            : Container();
      case 3:
        return firstGuessResult == true &&
                secondGuessResult == true &&
                thirdGuessResult == true
            ? const Icon(
                Icons.check_box,
                color: Colors.green,
              )
            : Container();
      default:
        return Container();
    }
  }

I am calling the function inside a loop that runs like below
 for (int i = 0; i < widget.listOfWords.length; i++)
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        widget.listOfWords[i],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: widget.firstGuessResults[i] == true
                              ? Colors.green
                              : Colors.redAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      widget.failedSecondAttempt
                          ? Text(
                              widget.listOfWords[i],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: widget.secondGuessResults[i] == true
                                    ? Colors.green
                                    : Colors.redAccent,
                              ),
                            )
                          : Container(),
                      widget.failedThirdAttempt
                          ? Text(
                              widget.listOfWords[i],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: widget.thirdGuessResults[i] == true
                                    ? Colors.green
                                    : Colors.redAccent,
                              ),
                            )
                          : Container(),
                      buildVerdict(context,
                          widget.firstGuessResults[i],
                          widget.secondGuessResults[i],
                          widget.thirdGuessResults[i]),

But i always get this Range error when i run the app.
The following IndexError was thrown building Results(dirty, state: _ResultsState#3bf32):
RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0


The value of widget.noOfAttempts is equal to one, this should mean that the firstGuessResult list should not be empty and run as normal, though the other lists (secondGuessResult, thirdGuessResult) would be empty, but the block of code concerning the use of those lists should not run and no error should be generated, yet the error persists. it feels like i am overlooking something that i cant quite figure out.
Full code for reference
// ignore_for_file: must_be_immutable, deprecated_member_use

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Results extends StatefulWidget {
  bool failedSecondAttempt;
  bool failedThirdAttempt;
  int noOfAttempts;
  final List listOfWords;
  List<bool> firstGuessResults;
  List<bool> secondGuessResults;
  List<bool> thirdGuessResults;

  Results({
    super.key,
    required this.failedSecondAttempt,
    required this.failedThirdAttempt,
    required this.listOfWords,
    required this.noOfAttempts,
    required this.firstGuessResults,
    required this.secondGuessResults,
    required this.thirdGuessResults,
  });

  @override
  State<Results> createState() => _ResultsState();
}

class _ResultsState extends State<Results> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget buildVerdict(BuildContext context, bool firstGuessResult,
      bool? secondGuessResult, bool? thirdGuessResult) {
    switch (widget.noOfAttempts) {
      case 1:
        return firstGuessResult == true
            ? const Icon(
                Icons.check_box,
                color: Colors.green,
              )
            : Container();
      case 2:
        return firstGuessResult == true && secondGuessResult == true
            ? const Icon(
                Icons.check_box,
                color: Colors.green,
              )
            : Container();
      case 3:
        return firstGuessResult == true &&
                secondGuessResult == true &&
                thirdGuessResult == true
            ? const Icon(
                Icons.check_box,
                color: Colors.green,
              )
            : Container();
      default:
        return Container();
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return false;
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              child: Column(children: [
                Center(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context, true);
                      },
                      child: const Text('Close')),
                ),
                for (int i = 0; i < widget.listOfWords.length; i++)
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        widget.listOfWords[i],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: widget.firstGuessResults[i] == true
                              ? Colors.green
                              : Colors.redAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      widget.failedSecondAttempt
                          ? Text(
                              widget.listOfWords[i],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: widget.secondGuessResults[i] == true
                                    ? Colors.green
                                    : Colors.redAccent,
                              ),
                            )
                          : Container(),
                      widget.failedThirdAttempt
                          ? Text(
                              widget.listOfWords[i],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: widget.thirdGuessResults[i] == true
                                    ? Colors.green
                                    : Colors.redAccent,
                              ),
                            )
                          : Container(),
                      buildVerdict(context,
                          widget.firstGuessResults[i],
                          widget.secondGuessResults[i],
                          widget.thirdGuessResults[i]),
                    ],
                  ),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Can you check if the size of final List listOfWords;   List<bool> firstGuessResults;   List<bool> secondGuessResults;   List<bool> thirdGuessResults; are same? Looks like at least one of them is empty.

Yes, atleast one of them is empty. but  listOfWords and firstGuessResults is never empty. but if you check the switch function, the lists that are empty are not supposed to be used depending on the value of widget,noOfAttempts

It looks likes one of your Guess Result list[firstGuessResults, secondGuessResults, thirdGuessResults] is empty or have length less than listOfWords which is causing this error to occur.

So how then should i proceed? The app is designed in such a way that, on the first attempt noOfAttempts = 1, second attempt noOfAttempts =2 and so on. therefore the secondGuessResults list must be empty if the user hasnt opted to use a second attempt, same for the third attempt.

try adding null check or isEmpty for those list empty list and don't make use of it if its empty

color: secondGuessResults.isNotEmpty && secondGuessResults.length >=i ? secondGuessResults[i] == true
? Colors.green
: Colors.redAccent : Colors.redAccent
try using the above code

you can omit "== true" if your list is List as it will check for true or false only, no need to mention it explicitly

You can try to call your Results with this input:
class ResultsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> listOfWords = ['Word1', 'Word2', 'Word3'];
    List<bool> firstGuessResults = [true, false, true];
    List<bool> secondGuessResults = [false, true, true];
    List<bool> thirdGuessResults = [true, true, false];

    return Results(
      failedSecondAttempt: true,
      failedThirdAttempt: true,
      listOfWords: listOfWords,
      noOfAttempts: 3,
      firstGuessResults: firstGuessResults,
      secondGuessResults: secondGuessResults,
      thirdGuessResults: thirdGuessResults,
    );
  }
}

Normally it could be work.
I think that one of firstGuessResults, secondGuessResults, thirdGuessResults is empty. (check also if listOfWords is empty)

This is hardcoding and it would not work for this app.

I know, I meant to use it only to test the input, because I think code it's ok but the input that he use it's wrong
